# How deep do I set metal post?

Tags: metal, post

How deep should I set a 14' steel pole in concrete that will have a wood roof attached. I am building a carport that is 36' long by 12' wide by 14' tall. There will be 8 poles.

Comment: First things first. I don't recommend you to stick steel poles directly into concrete at all. What you should do is when you set reinforcement bars you weld some anchor bolts (just to fix them).Then you pour concrete. When you have finished this then you can use some anchor plates (flat ones or "L" ones) with holes for the anchor bolts. Then you just fix these plates for the poles and that’s it. Now I know that this sounds complex but its right way to do it for many reasons. When it comes to how deep anchors should go in, let’s see what you can find and we can choose what’s best for this job.

Comment: Part of this answer would depend on where you put these poles in the ground and the type of soil. Here in the midwest usa poles should be at least 42" in the ground. Please add location information for a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given that 20 feet is a common stock steel length, 6 feet sounds good - if embedding them at all. It nearly meets the 2/3-1/3 rule-of-thumb for post above ground and post below ground. On more solid soils some get away with 3/4-1/4.

Comment: So auger, not post hole digger.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, we would put a footing and pedestal in.  Then you may not need to go as deep.  A 24" diameter footing 24" down with a 12" diameter pedestal should suffice if you do not enclose the carport.  The footing with the dirt on top is what resists the overturning.  The poles need to go into concrete close to the bottom.  Place rebar in the footing, and rebar connecting the pedestal to the footing in an "L" shape.  If you plan on putting walls on it, you would need to make the footing significantly larger and/or deeper, and the poles much bigger.